# Different results when running model.predict on the same input?

Tags: python, classification, keras, tensorflow

I have trained a Keras classification model with TensorFlow. Every time when I run the `model.predict(data)` on the same input data I get different results. The interesting thing is, for example, if I run 10 predicts on the same data, the average does give the correct classification. Is this normal behavior or have I done something horribly wrong?

Comment: This doesn't seem like correct behaviour, can you maybe share the code you are running multiple times?

Comment: Can you check whether there is a shuffle statement in your data? If that exists turn that off.